# Formulario para introducir HH:mm:ss en campo time

Tags: laravel, date

Estoy trabajando con Laravel. Tengo un campo de una tabla de tipo time: 00:00:00.

Si en el formulario pongo un input de tipo time solo me sale la opción de horas y minutos 00:00.

```
<div class="input-group">
<input id="halftime" name="halftime" class="form-control" type="text"
placeholder="00:00:00" value="{{ old('halftime') }}">
</div>
```

¿Como puedo hacer que me salgan también los segundos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que el campo de tipo time en tu formulario muestre también los segundos, debes usar el atributo "step" y establecerlo en "1" para que se muestren los segundos.

El código quedaría así:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input id="halftime" name="halftime" class="form-control" type="time" step="1"
    placeholder="00:00:00" value="{{ old('halftime') }}">
</div>
```

Además, debes asegurarte de que el campo de la base de datos que estás guardando sea de tipo time con segundos (p. ej., "00:00:00") y no solo con horas y minutos (p. ej., "00:00").

Si usas el tipo de dato "time" en el formulario y en la base de datos, y estableces el atributo "step" en "1", debería funcionar correctamente y mostrarte los segundos en el campo de tipo time en tu formulario.

Comment: Ha funcionado perfectamente, muchas gracias por la colaboración